# Is there a way I can dynamically increment the number of items being showed on the html page using ajax, php and plain js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**This is what I have**

*The JS file:*

```
var loadBtn = document.getElementById('loadButton');

loadBtn.addEventListener('click', fetchProducts);

let quantity = 3;

function fetchProducts() {

   quantity = quantity + 3;

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

   xhr.open('GET', `php/products.php?quantity=${quantity}`, true);

   xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status == 200) {
         var products = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

         var output, i;

         for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            output += `
                     <div id="pCard" class="p-card">
                           <p id="pName" class="p-name">${products[i].item_name}</p>
                           <p id="pAbout" class="p-about">${products[i].item_description}</p>
                     </div>
                     `;
         }

         document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = output;
      }
   }

   xhr.send();
}
```

*The PHP file:*

```
include 'config.inc.php';

$quantity = $_GET['quantity'];

$sqlFetch = "SELECT id,item_name,item_description FROM items ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $quantity";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlFetch);

$products = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($products);
```

I expected, after defining the quantity in the `js` file the `fetchProducts function` would increment the quantity of products and parse the `quantity` through `GET` to the `php` file.
Instead, this is what am getting from `products.php`:

```
Notice: Undefined index: quantity in C:\wamp64\www\simplesites\ss9_ajax\php\products.php on line 7
```

Comment: it should be doing what you suggest. It is always good practice to validate inputs to the server to ensure they are sane. You might consider testing the value of `$_GET['quantity']` prior to attempting to use it. Set it so some reasonable default if not defined. In your JavaScript, `quantity` is a global - so we have absolutely no idea what has happened to it prior to the call to `fetchProducts()`.

Comment: additionally, in your JavaScript `for()` loop I suspect you will be disappointed in the contents of `output` as it is undefined (not initialized) yet you concatenate a string to it. I suggest you initialize the `output` variable to an empty string;

Comment: Thanks for the `js for()` loop. Didn't realize that. I'm still getting errors on the `php` part though; `$_GET['quantity']` is not defined :(

Comment: It worked! I'm not sure what I did but it worked.